# Problem with ShrinkWrapping

Tags: mesh, modifiers, instances, shrinkwrap

hey quick question why is it that when i use shrinkwrap (or use any Deform Modifier) on instanced object the number of overall geometry doubles ?

I use Blender 3.0

Here is a blend file [image]

btw thx KickAir8p
for the help

if you open the file and shrinkwrap the instanced mesh yourself and the geometry count dosen't change pls tell me Thx

here are before and after photos of putting Any Deform modifier on instenced mesh

[image: before]

[image: After]

i heard that in order to deform instanced mesh it has to make it real is that true ?

Comment: Hi, congrats on your first question here!  That shouldn't be happening, and I've been unable to duplicate the problem.  A couple of screenshots (before & after) showing the problem and surrounding settings might be helpful.  Also, it's sometimes a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem.  Not sure about this time, but just so you know, the Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files:  https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: Sorry, on first reading I missed that you were doing this on an instanced object.  Yes, it's happening when I try it.  Wouldn't surprise me if it was normal behavior, but I don't know.  Hopefully someone else can be more helpful.